# MySQL query not working, probably missing a character somewhere?

Tags: mysql

I probably just missed a character somewhere but I can't seem to figure out where.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `paginas` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `naam` varchar NOT NULL,
  `inhoud` varchar,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

The error

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NOT NULL, `inhoud` varchar, PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CH' at line 3

Comment: and it doesn't come to mind to help us telling what it does? maybe an error? maybe what happens? ... Please put in some effort

Comment: It's an sql query I am trying to execute in PHPMYADMIN to create the table

Comment: I guess you already got an answer below, but next time do not use 'not working', copy-paste the actual error message you get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the length for `varchar` fields

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `paginas` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `naam` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `inhoud` varchar(255),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

[See fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4ad46)

Comment: That's impressive.  Exactly the same answer at exactly the same time.

Comment: These are rare cases,mostly you are the first and then i had to discard my saved draft :)